# Firebase network request monitoring not working with ionic 3 android

Tags: firebase, ionic3, firebase-performance

We are using ionic to develop android application and below are the firebase libraries and versions we have enabled.

```
com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.8
com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:16.2.4
```

We can see performance monitoring traces for the same, but network requests made within application are not monitored and hence this tab is always empty.

Kindly guide me how to solve this issue?

Expected to see network traffic in firebase console login

Comment: any updates on this issue? Did you find out how to monitor http requests in ionic app using firebase?

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Performance monitoring for Android only supports Android native apps written in Java or Kotlin.  It does not support cross platform app frameworks using different languages, so I would not expect it to pick up network traces for apps using ionic.